# Making an image float right in CSS?

Tags: css, image, html

Does anyone know why the following code isn't working:
The image remains towards the left of the screen.

HTML:

```
<div class"footerimg">
  <img src="./img/logo2.png" width="100px;" height="100px;">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footerimg {
  float:right;
}
```

Additional Info:
This div is inside another div called footer, but that shouldn't affect anything should it?
The CSS file IS linked to the page, I have started the style the footer.

Comment: You're missing an `=` after `class` for the `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

error :

```
<div class"footerimg">
```

should be

```
<div class = "footerimg">
       __^^^^__missing equal sign
```

Comment: Nice catch!! Good Observation.

Comment: @VedantTerkar : hehe...thankx mate....this is how i started my own HTML too... :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
footerimg>img{float:right;}
```

and add this in your html code:

```
class="footerimg"
```

you forgot the '='